# Structuring Bootstrap 3's Navbar to support left & right aligned content (desktop & mobile)

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to structure a Bootstrap nav bar such that I can have both left **and** right aligned content, while working for both desktop & mobile screens. I have a feeling like I'm trying to have my cake and eat it too here, but I would imagine that this should be possible.

*Note that in the screenshots below, the hamburger menu icon is just a custom image (e.g., not the default Bootstrap nav bar collapse icon).*

**This is what I want my mobile view to (roughly) look like:**
[image]

**But what I'm getting is this:**
[image]

**Here is the desktop version, only for comparison:**
[image]

And finally, here is the code I'm working with:

```html
<div id="navbar" class="navbar navbar-custom navbar-custom-bordered-header">
  <div class="navbar-header">
    <div class="navbar-brand">
      <img class="navbar-menu-button-custom" src="/assets/menu_button.png"/>
    </div>
    <a class="navbar-brand navbar-custom-brand" href="<%= root_path %>">My App</a>
  </div>
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" style="margin-right: 15px; width: auto;">
    <div class="navbar-brand">
      <a id="search" href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" style="color: white;" aria-hidden="true"></span></a>
    </div>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I'm just not sure what I need to do to achieve my desired view above. I can see that the problem appears to boil down to `navbar-header`'s width being too large:

[image]

But I'm not sure how to enforce a smaller width for `navbar-header` or just one that hugs `navbar-header`'s content. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your css file.

```
@media (max-width: 768px) {
.navbar-header {
max-width: 250px;
}
}
```

You may have to change 768 and 250 values according to your bootstrap setting. But most probably this will do.